# How to build a full generated maven module

Tags: java, maven, maven-module

I have this classical project tree:

```
project
  pom.xml
```

This pom.xml generates a full maven project with its own pom.xml like this:

```
project
  pom.xml
  generated-module
    pom.xml
    src
      ...
```

Is it possible to **generate** and **buid** this generated module with this simple command ?

```
mvn package
```

Comment: Have you tried doing `mvn package` ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a modules decleration in your parent-pom.xml

```
<project
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
        xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <groupId>myproject</groupId>
        <artifactId>PARENT</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <packaging>pom</packaging>
        <modules>
                <module>generated-module</module>
                <module>...</module>
        </modules>
</project>
```

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/reactor.html

Comment: the module-name is the artifactid of your child-project.

Comment: Sure, the problem is maven reactor is launched before build and it try to read pom.xml in 'generated-module' in order to determine build order, but 'generated-module' not exits! I think there is no good solution. I'll try with another way...

Comment: Maybe you can use the gmaven-plugin to control your build.